# How to configure Codeigniter to report all errors?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.3

I had a line - `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`, in CI's `autoload.php`. Because of this I was getting a blank page. When I removed the `'database'`, option then I started getting the output.

Now my question is not how to configure the database, but how to configure CI to speak its mind. When `'database'` was enabled all I got was a complete blank page. No error in php log, no error in Apache log, no error in CI log. In PHP I have set `E_ALL`. In my CI config I have set `log_threshold` to `4`, i.e. all messages should be logged. What more do I need to do?

Comment: Could you give the output of `phpinfo()` inside of your CI-Program? What does `trigger_error('test', E_USER_NOTICE)` give you?

Comment: @Lars Can you please let me know the exact section of phpinfo you want since, it outputs a really long list which I think cannot be posted here. BTW the output the `tigger_error` is `A PHP Error was encountered, Severity: User Notice, Message: test, Filename: controllers/welcome.php, Line Number: 22`. This came up in the browser window. In CI logs too it was logged as `ERROR - 2011-09-10 13:49:21 --> Severity: User Notice  --> test C:\....\lib\codeigniter\application\aceinvite\controllers\welcome.php 22`.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, that the error-settings are correct (which is proven by the trigger_error). It may be possible, that the autoloader does not throw any error messages or exceptions. You could still get lucky defining your own error handler, but I guess it will not help. Maybe someone else has an idea (beside debugging the autoload.php that is) - good luck! :)

Comment: This helped me, try it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

Comment: I found this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

It worked for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on your version of CI. For < 2.x edit the top level index.php and adjust the error_reporting function to use E_ALL"

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For >= 2.x edit the top level index.php and make sure ENVIRONMENT is set as:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

which sets the error_reporting to E_ALL.

Comment: I am using >= 2.x version and `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` is already defined at the top of index.php.

Comment: Accepting your answer since your answer is short and concise, even though my issue was something unrelated. Your answer is what 90% people would be looking for. For people who are still facing issue, they may want to look at my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Create a .htaccess file in your webroot with the following content

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Hopefully that should enable your logs.
Make sure to set the values to *off* and reporting to *0* on your production server :)

Answer (score 2):

Following environment settings would gonna force PHP to display errors as they occur:

- APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
  /*
- ERROR REPORTING

  if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
  {
      switch (ENVIRONMENT)
      {
          case 'development':
              // Report all errors
              error_reporting(E_ALL);

  ```
          // Display errors in output
          ini_set('display_errors', 1);
          break;

      case 'testing':
      case 'production':
          // Report all errors except E_NOTICE
          // This is the default value set in php.ini
          error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

          // Don't display errors (they can still be logged)
          ini_set('display_errors', 0);
      break;

      default:
          exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I am glad it worked for me in Codeignitor, would it work for all PHP frameworks or are there any limitations which bounds it to work for all PHP frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was the real reason but I had a PHP installation with left-over php.ini file. Later I installed the full WAMP stack with its own PHP. When I deleted the leftover php.ini file from the previous installation then it started working as it should. It seems the PHP binaries in the new installing was using using the left-over php.ini which was in totally different directory; maybe because that directory was in environment PATH.