# Codeigniter displays a blank page instead of error messages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, and instead of error messages I'm just getting a blank page. Is there any way to show PHP error messages instead? It's very hard to debug when I get no feedback.

My environment is Ubuntu with Apache.

Comment: how about giving details of your environment? My guess is that its on Windows with IIS..?

Comment: no I have ubuntu with apache.

Comment: Then please by all means, update your question with relevant details, as my guess was wrong.

Comment: @FlyingCat - I noticed you have yet to accept an answer.  I had the same problem, perhaps my solution was the one that eventually worked for you?

Comment: use mysqli driver instead of mysql in database.php

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Since none of the solutions seem to be working for you so far, try this one:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

This explicitly tells PHP to *display* the errors. Some environments can have this disabled by default.

This is what my environment settings look like in `index.php`:

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            // Report all errors
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            // Display errors in output
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            // Report all errors except E_NOTICE
            // This is the default value set in php.ini
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

            // Don't display errors (they can still be logged)
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't worked in my case. my website showing blank page even after placing - // Report all errors
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            // Display errors in output
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: how to enable only debug and error message only in codeigniter ,

no need 3 = Informational Messages
| 4 = All Messages

Answer (score 31):

Make sure `php5-mysql` is installed.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and after 20 minutes of debugging (using the tips presented in other answers) I found out that CodeIgniter serves blank page just because php5-mysql is missing. So I hope my answer will save someone's time.

Comment: I've encountered this same problem a few times. Codeigniter really needs a patch for this behavior. In fact, I'm going to pull their repo and look into it myself. +1 to you sir.

Comment: While not EXACTLY my problem, it was very closely related.  For windows users, make sure to include your php and php\ext folder in your PATH variable and then restart apache....

Comment: +1 to alexander and thank you. Same problem here installing for LLMP (Lighttpd, Mariadb). You get distracted for a moment and you type "sudo apt-get install php5-cgi" and miss "php5-mysql". It's a pity there's nothing to tell you what just happened if you don't already have a basic non-codeigniter php5 database example to run already.

Comment: +1 Had to dig out an old site I did in CI, I knew I hadn't set up.the DB, you just presume it will throw an error somewhere along the way if that's the issue. I was blaming nginx until I saw this, apt-get and voila the DB connection error I would have liked to have seen yesterday.

Comment: This was my problem as well. I would have been nice if some sort of "can't connect to database" or something had been displayed. Odd it wasn't, even with full logging enabled...

Comment: Spot on, you just saved my sanity!

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem and as Shayan Husaini pointed out, I had an undetected syntax error.

I solved it using the php linter in the terminal:

```
php -l file.php
```

You can also use something like this to use the linter in every file in some folder:

```
find -type f -name "*.php" -exec php -l '{}' \;
```

And to filter just the ones with errors:

```
find -type f -name "*.php" -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep '^[^N]'
```

That should show files with parsing errors and the line where the error is.

Comment: you might need to quote the *.php part `find -type f -name '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep '^[^N]'`

Comment: Brilliant solution mate this worked perfectly for me

Comment: this was the best option in the end, i've ended up installing a php lint extension in Atom and it changed everything.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior occurs when you have basic php syntax error in your code. In case when you have syntax errors the php parser does not parse the code completely and didnot display anything so all of the above suggestion would work only if you have other than syntax errors.

Comment: I agree. I just need those base syntax error shown cauz I miss ; or ' a lot. +1

Comment: I have faced same situation too many times but did not find anything working. My suggestion is to use good IDE like dreamweaver CS5 which prompts you for syntax errors.

Answer (score 6):

you can set it in the main index.php

```
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have these code when I opened my index.php. Not sure why the error won't display. +1 though.

Comment: try to put the same code into each controller you use and test, in this way you should see where the error is

Comment: Ya, but it's not very efficient, I just wish php error handling would work.

Answer (score 5):

This happens to me whenever I do autoload stuff in autoload.php like the 'database'

To resolve this, If you're using Windows OS

1. Open your php.ini. 
     Search and uncomment this line - `extension=php_mysql.dll`

   (Please also check If the PHP directive points to where your extensions is located. 
    Mine is `extension_dir = "C:\php-5.4.8-Win32-VC9-x86\ext"`)
2. Restart Apache and refresh your page

Comment: This helped me to resolve this problem with a CI project that I tried to open up using WT-NMP.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem a couple days ago. My development environment is Win8 and the website was working just fine, but when i uploaded the files to production server (Linux) was displaying a blank page.

Turns out that [models and controllers's filenames should start with a uppercase letter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html).

> The file must be called ‘Blog.php’, with a capital ‘B’.
>
> Class names must start with an uppercase letter.

In windows environment this wont matter since [windows does not differentiate uppercase and lowercase](https://superuser.com/questions/165975/are-all-versions-of-windows-case-insensitive), but in linux environment, the files wont be displayed.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: This fixed my problem but not the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your index.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a blank index.html file in your root folder. It happens :)

Comment: Sjees, it does happen. In my case there was a default index.html on a clean installed lamp unit. Thanks for pointing me to the thing I obviously should have checked 8-D

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CI 2.0 or newer, you could change `ENVIRONMENT` type in your `index.php` to `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing');`.
Alternatively, you could add `php_flag display_errors on` to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks Vyrautas, I tried your way and it gave me server error 500 now if I have errors. Still don't show the php error message. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

check if error_reporting is ON at server or not, if that id off you wont get any errors and just blank page. if you are on a shared server then you can enable error reporting via htaccess. In codeIgniter add following in your htaccess

```
php_flag display_errors On
```

and set

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR); ## or what ever setting desired in php
```

hope it will work for you

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to give the permission of your Codeigniter folder, It's might be the permission issue and then start your server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the exact issue i have faced, before i posted. In my case also there is no error message displayed, only blank page comes. I have given permission to CI folder in ubantu and restarted the apache server and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In your `index.php` file add the line:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Answer (score 1):

In `system/core/Common.php` there is an exception handler, with a block of code that looks like this:

```
 // We don't bother with "strict" notices since they tend to fill up
 // the log file with excess information that isn't normally very helpful.
if ($severity == E_STRICT)
{
    return;
}
```

By removing the `if` and the `return` and the incorrect comment, I was able to get an error message, instead of just a blank page. This project isn't using the most recent version of CodeIgniter, hopefully they've fixed this bug by now.

Answer (score 0):

load your url helper when you create a function
eg,

```
visibility function_name () {

     $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

the it will show you errors or a view you loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the @ symbol anywhere?

If you have something like:

```
@include('page_with_error.php');
```

You will get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this because I had a CLI running via cron as the root user, thus creating log files with root:root. When you tried to navigate to a URI everything would work fine but CI exhibiting the blank page likely because it didn't have write permission to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter doesn't seem to throw an error message when I was referencing a view that did not exist.

In my example I had within my controller:

```
$this->load->view('/admin/index/access_controls/groups/add');
```

Because the file did not exist, I got a blank "An error has occurred page".  I changed the code to:

```
$this->load->view('/admin/access_controls/groups/add');
```

This was how I resolved the same issue you seem to be having, hope this helps someone some day.

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing the same problem and tried almost all the things but finally i restarted my server and i found everything started working fine..i don't know how.....i think it was some server side problem that's why my PHP CODE was not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your php.ini:

```
display_error = On;
```

and you have this in your CI Application at the same time

```
error_reporting(0);
```

you'll get HTTP/1.1 200 OK and a completely bank page.

That's because when display_error is on, the php-fpm always return HTTP code 200.
And all the errors to output are forbidden by error_reporting(0).

For CI application,the entry index.php sets up the running environment as bellows:

```php
if(isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ENV'])) {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', $_SERVER['SERVER_ENV']);
} else {
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

In short, when you set ENV directive in your webserver's conf,say Nginx's fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ENV         production;
```

then CI will automatically set

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to see if you've surpassed the error checking in your code by accident. Search all your code for any instance of error_reporting(). If you call it without parameters, it just returns the current level, and is harmless. If you call it *with* a parameter, such as 0 (zero), it will turn off error reporting.

You can test for this in CodeIgnitor by looking at their core library under ../system/core/Common.php and finding a section that's at about line 615 that looks like:

```
if (($severity & error_reporting()) !== $severity)
{
   return;
}
```

Add something like:

```
if (($severity & error_reporting()) !== $severity)
{
   echo "Suppressing errors!";
   return;
}
```

and you should be able to trap for surpassed errors, and debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

Often when codeigniter displays nothing, there is a syntax error. Mostly if the app was running seamlessly previously, just look around your most recent edits. For me the experience this time was the entire app, not just a page. So I did a quick brain scan for the most recent edits I had done and worked backwards, reviewing each file I had worked on this day. Turned out to be some 'where' clauses in two model files: For instance, I had

```
$this->db->where('Type' => 'Blog'); rather than $this->db->where('Type', 'Blog');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, i installed latest xamp version and found my site is not working, after research and wasting time i found that.

I need to turn on following tag in php.ini file short_open_tag=On

Make sure to restart apache after doing this.

Hope this helps, most of these problems are related to php.ini file or fresh installation if your site was already running as other people facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

after installation of xamp/wamp you may notice few errors of similar nature. If your website was already running dont worry, it is a configuration related issue.

1) check database connections in database.php file  inside application folder
2) check config.php file check url is correct or not?
3) by default short tags are off in new installations then follow the procedure below

in php.ini file change "short_open_tag=Off" to "short_open_tag=On"

Make sure to restart apache after doing this.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error, In my case, was occurring because my Apache server was configured to run `PHP` as `Fast CGI`, I changed it to `FPM` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who is still looking for answers:

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';  (make sure you use mysqli, not mysql).  (database.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you get net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in the console then you are using gzip in your .htaccess file but gzip encoding is Off.

Enable `zlib.output_compression=On` in `php.ini` and restart Apache

Answer (score -1):

please check either error folder is in application folder of not
in my case i replace error folder in application folder