# CodeIgniter Blank Page

Tags: codeigniter

n00b here. After searching the forums I have not yet come across this problem as I am experiencing it.

I have a CI site that was working correctly until about three days ago. My problem is as follows:

On button click - Page Loads correctly.

On Enter press - CI Blank Page of Death loads.

For example: When I login, after the login process has run it must reroute me to the Dashboard, unless I still have a temporary password where I get rerouted to the "Change Password" screen first and then to the Dashboard.

AS LONG AS I USE THE BUTTONS AND CLICK THEM EVERYTHING WORKS.

On ENTER PRESS, I get the Blank Screen of Death.
However, on TAB to BUTTON and then ENTER it works.

The problem is not consistent however. I have some processes that do not have views attached and NONE of them will run - hit ENTER and get blank. They are all failing on ENTER PRESS.

I am slowly going off my trolley. Logging is ON, Directories for cache and logs are 775. NOTHING is showing in my logs...

Comment: do you have a live link to the application where the problem can be replicated?

Comment: similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

Comment: Can you show us the html for your form?

Comment: @ Naeem... Thanks for the link. I have gone through that page very carefully.

My issue is the following: 
EVERYTHING WORKS CORRECTLY if I CLICK on a BUTTON. 
I only get the blank page when I hit the enter key.

This was all working correctly until last week when this behaviour started on both my dev server and production. They are both hosted with Hetzner.de and they have not done anything to the servers. I am inclined to think it is something I did but as yet I found anything... The site works as developed IF I click a button. It used to work on enter press too, but is now blank screening.

Comment: Another thing is on click I get the normal notifications about the loading. On enter press I get nothing in the logs and no source in the blank page. I also need this process to work as I have some controllers without views that are now not running either. I have copied the complete site into a fresh CI 2.3 install and the problem is persisting, which makes me believe I broke something. I just have no clue as to why it works correctly on click and not on enter. ???

Comment: OK... Sorry about the comment above... Problem was persisting because of FILTHY data being used to test with. Data problems fixed. Site is now exhibiting the correct behaviour on enter press and button click on the fresh CI 2.3 install.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort everyone!!!  If anyone has any ideas about what the problem could have been please post your best guesses. I only know enough about PHP to be dangerous... LOL!!! I'm going to vote for Kali's answer below although the error logging did not actually reveal anything as to what the problem was. The server was backed up and a whole lot of controllers, views, models and the config file uploaded from development. This was indeed a VERY STRANGE problem... No log info, no nothing except blank screen on enter and correct behaviour on click... WEIRD INDEED!!!

Comment: In the future, try to make your questions less obnoxious. There is no need for the all caps button. EVER.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First Try to active error handlers for displaying of errors for addittional info to post here what error is occuring..

```
 // change settings for error handler to show errors
        // $this setup is used for checking errors for development to be shown.... 
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

by the way if your using CI version 2 higher
you can see it in its index.php file an configuration for displaying error also.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); //just set up environtment to development
```

Comment: My problem is that the page works completely correctly when I press a button but not when I hit enter.

Comment: All error reporting is on according to the link Naeem gave above.

Answer (score 3):

Even though there are accepted answers I wanted to add a way that worked for me to figure out this problem.

Usually the "Blank Page" indicates a PHP parsing error somewhere in the code.  Strange thing for me was that on my local MAMP based test server the code ran fine.  I FTP it to my hosted server and all of a sudden, blank page of death.

Even though I had errors on, log errors on, display errors on, nothing appears in any log file.

I was able to find the error by a funny little trick.   I added an echo line in CodeIgniter.php in the system/core.   Obviously hacking the core was not a great idea but all I wanted to do was to see how far it was getting in the load process.

When my echo appeared after trying to load a page on the remote hosted server it also displayed the parsing problem in a derived controller!  Not sure why the error did not come out without the "echo" added.  But adding it seemed to trigger some output to be generated, IE my echo line and the PHP parse error was appended.

Not sure if this will help anyone but it turned out to be a nice easy way to find the error which only showed on the remote server.

Obviously, don't forget to put your core file back to its original state without the echo.

Comment: This actually helped me and probably saved me from hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by copying the application into a fresh CI 2.3 install.

I have no idea what actually caused this "erratic" behaviour.

The application worked correctly as designed whenever a BUTTON was CLICKED but gave the blank death screen when ENTER was PRESSED.

This inconsistent behaviour is what threw me. The fact that my logs (CI and APACHE) also showed nothing was also very strange. Had this been a parse error, surely the behaviour on "Click" and on "Enter Press" should have been the same.

My non-view controllers for various ad-hoc admin jobs are now also working correctly, which they were not before, as they use "Enter Press" (having no buttons to "Click").

I am still going to invite best guesses as to why this behaviour occurred the way it did.

Surely someone out there (Phil Sturgeon et al) with extensive CI experience has encountered this non-consistent blank screen behaviour and knows what caused it.

Thank you to all the people who took the time and effort to assist me!!!

Big UP!!! StackOverflow!!!

Answer (score 0):

probably error in INCLUDE  login.php

Answer (score 0):

My problem was Apache stop working because of ...Skype! Skype actually work on the same 443 and Apache didn't start! I hate this Skype! Bring me nuts for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Installing php5-pgsql worked for me