# CodeIgniter - Blank white page on some systems

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter, debugging

I have a codeigniter project under development that is working fine on most of the systems. But one of my client is getting a blank white page on one of his laptop. I turned on codeigniter logging. I asked the client to login from his side, then I examined the log and there is no fatal error in the logs. There are some php warnings and notices, beside those the log is not indicating anything unusual. How can I find the cause of this issue? I also looked into apache error logs and nothing seems to be wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter displays a blank page instead of error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages)

Comment: If you try creating a simple hello world page CI, can you check if it works on your clients browser?

Comment: @Krimson Yes most of the pages are working fine. Page after the login is not working fine on his browser. The client used another system and logged in just fine.

Comment: What browser is your client using? If I had access to your clients laptop, I would examine the http headers being sent. Maybe the client's browser isn't accepting cookies. It's hard speculating what might be wrong.

Comment: Probably on client side, do you have some js which redirect users or are needed to display the page ? Is it only one specific page or all ? Can we have some code (Controller and view) ?

Comment: @Krimson my client tried all browsers Firefox, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: @AdrienXL on server side I am redirecting after successful login. On client's browser, I can see the redirected url but no page.

Comment: Do you get a blank page when you point your browser to the redirected url without logging in? If yes, I would say the client's browser isn't accepting cookies and so when the client goes to the redirected url, the server side code can't identify your client as logged in because the client doesn't have a (session)cookie to send back. Hence it stops the execution of your script. Again this is just a speculation and really depends on the way you have set up your server side code.