# smarty not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, templates, smarty

I installed Smarty in Codeigniter and it's not really working. Here is what I did:

1. I followed this instructions:

   http://sunwebexpert.com/books/detail/PHP/integrating-smarty-and-codeigniter.html

But I also put another file in the library: parser.php which is a library to do parsing (I've used it before with smarty and worked well)

2. the on Codeigniter's autoload.php wrote this:

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('parser','smarty');
   ```
3. On main controller I wrote this function to test:

   ```
   public function index()
   {
     $this->data['d'] = 2;
     $this->parser->parse('base/test.tpl', $this->data);
   }
   ```

but the result is no error display and I see the variable 'd' as it is wrote in the template:

```
{$d}
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why can't I see the variable value if I installed smarty as I did before in other projects?
2. How can I enable to see errors if there are?

Comment: answer of 2: in your root folder of CoideIgniter, open the `index.php` file and around line 21, set `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`. This will enable you to show any error, warning, notice messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in codeigniter, there is a built-in library called [Parser](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html). That's why this may cause conflict with your library name. Try to rename your library name or use built-in library.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages#9589988) is how to display error on codeigniter.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: thank you. Yesterday I could figure it out with a friend's help and this was the problem. I was using another Parser class, not codeigniter's one.