# Image not displayed in codeigniter while displaying image?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have successfully uploaded an image path with an image name in my database. But when it comes to display it doesn't work. I have filed profilepic in my DB.I don't know where I am going, wrong please help to sort.

```
// Controller

    public function index() {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_login')) {
            $this->load->model('Display_profilepic');
            $data = $this->Display_profilepic->getImage();
            print_r($data);//nothing printed
            $data=array('profile_picture'=>$img);
            $this->load->view("my_profile",$data);



            }

// model Display_profilepic

    function getImage(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('tbl_usrs');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()==0)
    echo("Picture not found!");
    else{
    $data = $query->row_array();
    return $data['profile_picture'];
    print_r($data['profile_picture']);//nothing printed
```

I have a seprate controller and model for inserting the image into the DB where the path is defined. Let me know if I should post that also.

Comment: There is a return statement before the print_r function. Also, the { at the end of  the else statement is not needed (and should be causing an error).

Comment: when i see the page source on my browser "<img title="profile image" class="img-circle img-responsive" src=" ">" is displayed

Comment: try replacing your view as <img title="profile image" class="img-circle img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('Controller/function').$img; ?>">

Comment: what is in `profile_picture` in table??

Comment: @Abdulla its like path/name of image like upload/large/this.jpg

Comment: basically $img value is not returned why??

Comment: `profile_picture` contained in user table??

Comment: yes profile_picture is column in table tbl_usrs

Comment: @Optimmus can you print $data and $query->num_rows() and check output

Comment: @user1048123 nothing is printed :( did my controller and model didn't loaded properly bcoz when i change model name in $this->load-.>model('did') no error is give like undefined property

Comment: $query->num_rows()  should retrun some value. Is you error_reporting is on ? check your log..

Comment: nothing is displayed error_reporting is on

Comment: print $this->db->last_query() and check. also try to print some thing in your model and check that its come there or not

Comment: yup not a not single thing is being printed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85373/discussion-between-user1048123-and-optimmus).

Comment: are you able to see some thing from controller when echo or print

Comment: have you included   $this->load->database(); in construct function

Comment: yup i have included it

Comment: @user1048123 can help me...

Comment: @Optimmus are you able to see some thing from controller when echo or print. Print Like 
echo 'printed';
$data = $this->Display_profilepic->getImage();
            print_r($data)

Comment: nothing is displayed not a single error

Comment: are you getting blank page ? you are not able to see echo 'printed' ?

Comment: not able to see echo or print other stuff are visible even if i change the model name to see what happens no error is displayed

Comment: are you using apache ?
function getImage(){ echo 'here';exit;;}.let me know ouput
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :)

**model:**

```
    function getImage()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
        $r=$this->db->get('tbl_usrs');
        if($r->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($r -> result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $r->free_result();
        return $data;
    }
```

Make sure your $id is not null. So check that once.

Comment: i am getting undefined variable $data in model and $img in controller

Comment: Have you solved you above issue? of undefined $data and $img ?