# Codeigniter display blank page and no errors

Tags: codeigniter

When I access my application, browser display blank page like this :

[image]

There is no error

My application using `codeigniter`

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages try this

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I have try that. In console : `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/spsubagent/index.php"`

Comment: share your index function code

Comment: Check your default controller has first letter upper case for class and file name.

Comment: taking to account that there is 2016 in a calendar try [phalcon](https://www.phalconphp.com) :) _sorry for offtopic_

Comment: if serious - at least one question you have to clarify: how do you run your app? (e.g. are you using lampp, apache, php embedded webserver etc.)

Comment: Do check [this url](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644990/why-am-i-getting-a-500-internal-server-error-message) where explain why 500 internal server error occur. Also try to print errors using "ini_set('display_errors', 1);"

Answer (score 1):

Probably your environment is not displaying errors. This can be because your php.ini configuration or because the definition of the constant ENVIRONMENT in **spsubagent/index.php**.

If your php.ini are configured correctly, so you '**ENVIROMENT**' constant must be defined with 'development' value to display errors, because the 'production' value must hide errors.

**Bad practice:**

You can force the exibition of the error defining the `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the construct of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccess file or replace your htaccess file with new htaccess file for codeigniter.