# Codeigniter DATABASE Trouble

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

The thing is when i use this code

in my **model**  :

```
public function get_all_subject_tasks(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('task'); 
$this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));  
$this->db->order_by("task_id", "desc");    
$query_result=$this->db->get();
$result=$query_result->result();
return $result;
}
```

in my **controller**:

```
public function subjects($t,$action=""){
        $data=array();
        $data['subject_tasks']=$this->Schoolmodel->get_all_subject_tasks($t);
        if($action=='asyn'){
          $this->load->view('theme/task',$data);
        }else{    
          $this->load->view('theme/include/header');
        $this->load->view('theme/include/school_sidebar');
          $this->load->view('theme/task',$data);
          $this->load->view('theme/include/footer');
        }
    }
```

in my **php page**:

```
<div class="panel-body">
       <table id="teacher_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <th>Name</th><th><?php get_phrase('teacher_email') ?></th><th width="110"><?php get_phrase('action') ?></th>
       <?php foreach($subject_tasks as $list){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td class="task_name"><?php echo $list->task_name ?></td>
        <td class="task_desc"><?php echo $list->task_desc ?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I get all of the tasks that are in the database, without any subject filter.

So my question is
How do i make the page echo the **tasks based on which subject** they are in?

---

Also here is how i have setup my **database structure**

1. subject_id
2. task_id
3. task_name
4. task_desc
5. user_id

Where subject_id is the id of the subject where the task is inserted in.

Comment: What is your problem now? The `where` inside model is incorrect.

Comment: My problem is that i only want the tasks that are in a certain subject to be displayed on the task page. How do i correct the "where" code in the model?

Comment: Do you get an error or all tasks are being displayed? How is the routing configured?

Comment: I dont get anything displayed at all, no data from the database is being displayed.  This is how the link is looking  http://www.domain.com/School/subjects/14

Comment: First you need to [display errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages) to find out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

// your model

public function getTask($subject_id)
{
    $result = $this->db
        ->where("subject_id", $subject_id) // !!!
        ->where("user_id", $this->session->userdata('user_id')) // !!!
        ->order_by("task_id", "desc")
        ->get('tasks');

    return $result->num_rows() > 0 ?
        $result->result() : false;
}

// your class

class School extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==FALSE){
            redirect('User');
        }
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Schoolmodel');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function subjects($subject_id,$action=""){
        $data=array();
        $data['subject_tasks'] = $this->Schoolmodel->getTask($subject_id);
        if($action=='asyn'){
            $this->load->view('theme/task',$data);
        }else{
            $this->load->view('theme/include/header');
            $this->load->view('theme/include/school_sidebar');
            $this->load->view('theme/task',$data);
            $this->load->view('theme/include/footer');
        }
    }

}

?>

// your view

    <div class="panel-body">
           <table id="teacher_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <th>Name</th><th><?php get_phrase('teacher_email') ?></th><th width="110"><?php get_phrase('action') ?></th>
    <?php if(false !== $subject_tasks) { foreach($subject_tasks as $list){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="task_name"><?php echo $list->task_name ?></td>
            <td class="task_desc"><?php echo $list->task_desc ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use ->select(*) if you'd like to select all fields.

Comment: You can use ->get('table') instead ->from('table') and ->get();  , its better to use method chaining :)  ->met1()->met2()->...

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work:

```
$this->db->where("subject_id",$subject_id AND "user_id",$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

From [Active Record documentations](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html): Multiple calls to `where` will result in `AND`:

```
$this->db->where("subject_id", $subject_id);
$this->db->where("user_id", $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

Comment: Thank you @Amir for the assistance.