# Codeigniter AWS instance blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried to deploy a codeigniter app on AWS free tier account. I created a hello world project and deployed it and it is successfully running. So PhP is installed fine and working as expected.

But when i try to run the actual project, i just get a blank page. Please find below the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

I have deployed the same on Bluehost and is working fine. Tried enabling errors under production and development for index.php using the following.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

There are no errors and just a blank page. The error_log is also empty.
Can anyone please suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you installed LAMP in order to execute PHP pages?

Comment: Yes, as suggested above, i have run a hello world codeigniter project and its working fine

Comment: Are you getting an issue while redirecting to other page is it?

Comment: Nope, the landing page itself is blank!!

Comment: Without looking at code, its bit difficult to say something. Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages .. Let me know, if issue gets resolved

Comment: Have tried enabling the errors, no luck!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145527/discussion-between-pramod-patil-and-rafavinu).