# How to create Rest API in codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter-3

To create simple Rest API I have followed below steps
downloaded `CodeIgniter-restserver` 
and copy pasted `REST_Controller` from downloaded file into libraries under my project(`src` is the project name).
And then created Api.php inside controller of my project

```
<?php
require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class API extends REST_Controller {

    function test()
    {
        echo "RESTfull API";
    }
}
?>
```

`And I run the URL`http://localhost/src/index.php/Api/test in `postman` but it is not showing results.

Comment: I suggest you enable error reporting in your `php.ini` file, ie `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the below link
https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/codeigniter-3-restful-api-tutorialexample.html

and then after you run the code you will get a small error
Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/rest_controller_lang.php

The problem is that codeigniter can't find the rest_controller translations. You just need to create this file /application/languages/english/rest_controller_lang.php

Then copy & paste this code inside:

```
<?php
/*
 * English language
 */
$lang['text_rest_invalid_api_key'] = 'Invalid API key %s'; // %s is the REST API key
$lang['text_rest_invalid_credentials'] = 'Invalid credentials';
$lang['text_rest_ip_denied'] = 'IP denied';
$lang['text_rest_ip_unauthorized'] = 'IP unauthorized';
$lang['text_rest_unauthorized'] = 'Unauthorized';
$lang['text_rest_ajax_only'] = 'Only AJAX requests are allowed';
$lang['text_rest_api_key_unauthorized'] = 'This API key does not have access to the requested controller';
$lang['text_rest_api_key_permissions'] = 'This API key does not have enough permissions';
$lang['text_rest_api_key_time_limit'] = 'This API key has reached the time limit for this method';
$lang['text_rest_ip_address_time_limit'] = 'This IP Address has reached the time limit for this method';
$lang['text_rest_unknown_method'] = 'Unknown method';
$lang['text_rest_unsupported'] = 'Unsupported protocol';
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814) line by line. This is the best solution for beginners to use CodeIgniter Rest API library.

```
<?php
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class API extends REST_Controller {

    function test_get()
    {

    $data = array("message"=>"RESTfull API");
    $this->response($data);
    }
}
?>
```

call: `http://localhost/src/index.php/Api/test`

**Note:** In rest API you should define the method type as `GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE`

[How to use the Rest API library in CodeIgniter](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)

Comment: I tried same nothing showing in postman and followed same doc only

Comment: What issue is you getting now?

Comment: Yeah I opened nothing it is showing in browser also :(

Comment: you mean, it's diaplying blank page. if it is then enable error reporting as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

Comment: Change controller name API to Api in Api.php

Comment: Can you open it in browser and share screen?

Comment: Please turn off inspect element of browser then share screen

Comment: Okay now first you should resolve blank page issue. Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class Api extends REST_Controller {

    function test_get()
    {
      $data = array('response' => 'RESTfull API');

      if(count($data ) > 0)
      {
         $this->response($data ,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
      }
      else
      {
         $error = array('message' => 'No record found');
         $this->response($error,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
      }   
}
```

For more pls read : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814

Comment: Your class name should be `Api` change it from `API` and hit url like this `http://localhost/src/index.php/Api/test` or use like this  `http://localhost/src/index.php/api/test`

Comment: some thing is wrong on your side : see this : https://imgur.com/a/TlEna3u

Comment: can you tell me what steps you followed..  I followed above steps it is not working so i'm asking again.. could you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
    require(APPPATH'.libraries/REST_Controller.php');

    class ApiController extends REST_Controller {

        function test()
        {
            echo "RESTfull API";
            die;
        }
    }
?>
```

I suggest to use built-in method `response` from the library

Comment: @GonnaHack: consider to rename your class name to `ApiController` and the filename as well, should be `ApiController.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try lowercase: `api/test` instead of `Api/test`

Upd. Add to config/routes.php

```
$route['api/test'] = 'api/test';
```

Another one thing, if you have routes try figure out, does they use pluralize, if it foes, so you can try to check `/apis/test` instead of `/api/test`
because pluralize transform controller name from  one to many form (sorry for primitive English)

Comment: Did you have a router? And i should ask, you run it under apache/nginx at 80 port?

Comment: Do you add route to config/routes.php file?

Comment: I changed but nothing is working.. even I changed in routes also