# PHP error webpage displays notices but not errors

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and I'm having a trouble with the "A PHP error was encountered" page.

If I'm causing an error with `severity = notice`, the page is correctly displayed. For example:

```
<?php echo e; die(); ?>
```

However, when causing an error with `severity = error`, the page is basically a blank page with just a single word "Error". For example, this code:

```
<?php echo 'e' die(); ?>
```

A screenshot of the output here: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v3lT.png)

The error logs are correct, though:

```
ERROR - 2019-07-25 15:19:51 --> Severity: error --> Exception: syntax error, unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT), expecting ',' or ';' [url]/controllers/Project.php 31
```

Any idea how to get the error page back?

**UPDATE**
The bug disappeared by itself this morning. I guess there was some sort of strange Apache bug... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Read this page:
[Codeigniter displays a blank page instead of error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages)

Comment: I did, and ensured the error_reporting / display_errors were correctly set. Also, I'd like to emphasize that contrary to this discussion you cite, I do obtain some outputs (the correct error page for notices, and a (single) word otherwise). I therefore think it's a different issue.