# Cant send email in Codeigniter, no error message. Local or remote

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using MAMP and CodeIgniter 2.1.3(the latest) and trying to send an email. I have read various tutorials and as far as I can see my code has no errors in it. I need some help deciphering where the problem is as every time I run the function, local or when I have uploaded it, I receive only a blank page. **Nothing is being printed on screen at all.**

I have tried setting out the `$config` array both ways I know and nothing changes. I.e. `$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';` and `$config = Array( 'protocol' => 'smtp', 'smtp_host => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com');`

I can't understand why its not working, I've been through the email library and I have all the config written right. Is there some syntax error that I cannot see?

```
<?php 

class Email extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {


        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['mail_path'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com'
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'PASSWORD';

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('MYEMAIL@gmail.com', 'THIS GUY');
    $this->email->to('MYEMAIL@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email test bitches');
    $this->email->message('This is working, I hope');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo "Da email, da email, wut wut da emails";
        }else{
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

        }
    }
}
```

**The error that I have got to print on screen is as follows**

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$config' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/codeigniter/application/controllers/email.php on line 18

So then I saw that it lacked a `;` and I put it in but now the page doesn't load :/. Added `ssl://` and now I have an error report from Google. At least I can work with this.

Thank you :)

Comment: try getting rid of the `ssl://` in your config variables

Comment: Nope :( same result, nothing printed on screen not even an error

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a fatal error elsewhere?  Try commenting out the constructor or turning up your error reporting level.  Also, try putting an `echo "it works; return;` as the first instruction in `index()`, and see if that works.

Comment: The only way I get any response is when I comment out everything but an echo. Commenting out the constructer doesn't help for some reason

Comment: sup yo? you gotta get the error messages.

Comment: @SoundsofTheDot You know I be getting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get error. Probably you are in production environment and the error reporting is turned off. The problem is with your constructor. Change it with this-

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Turn error reporting on. [Check how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370391/how-to-configure-codeigniter-to-report-all-errors)

EDIT:

You forgot to put semicolon in this line

```
$config['smtp_user'] = 'MYEMAIL@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Nope :( this hasn't helped, and my environment is already defined as development and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` also :(

Comment: Have you changed the constructor? With your previous constructor, you should get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::Controller() in ...`

Comment: Yep changed the Constructor. Actually I added another line into the error reporting and I'm now getting an error finnally!! I'll put it in the question

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was the constructor part. But I had tried to change so many things it took a while to get back to it