# how to load my model in to autoload file because of this i get blank page?

Tags: codeigniter

I had a line -

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');,
```

in codeigniter `autoload.php` . Because of this I was getting a blank page. When I removed the `database`, option then I started getting the output.

now I want to load my database please tell me how to load  it ?

thank u

Comment: Remove duplicating DB loading if you have it in model too. Turn on error reporting and display_errors to see what is root of issue. Find something useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370391/how-to-configure-codeigniter-to-report-all-errors).

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be syntax error in your autoload.php file.Remove comma next to array('database'); as displayed in your code.