# Delete function using AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

**PROBLEM SOLVED**.. I update my code accordingly.. Thanks all

Intro: My code display array of message traces (each message display in grey-panel). User can delete unwanted message by click on delete button, the message will be deleted in both DB and disappear from screen.

Seems my delete function is not working.. Appreciate for advice.. I don't know AJAX.. this is my first try. Thanks in advance.

The following are my code:

ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var $btn = $(this),
             $li = $btn.closest('li');

        var traceId = $li.data('trace-id');

        jQuery.ajax({
                  type: 'post', 
                  url: 'traceDelete', 
                  dataType: 'text',

                  data: { 'traceId': traceId },

                  success: function (res) {
                      if (res === '1') {
                          $btn.fadeOut();
                      }
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                      alert(thrownError);
                  }
        });
    });
```

part of view code:

```
<ul id="responds">
    <?php foreach ($line as $dataName => $contents){ ?>    
        <li data-trace-id="<?php echo $contents->trace_id; ?>">
            <div class="grey-panel" style="text-align:right">
                <div class="del_wrapper" id="<?php echo $contents->trace_id; ?>">
                    <a href="#" class="del_button" id="<?php echo $contents->trace_id; ?>" data-hover="tooltip" title="Delete this message <?php echo $contents->trace_id; ?>"  >
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <?php print $contents->trace_hdr.'<br />';
                  print $contents->trace_src.'<br />';
                  print $contents->trace_dest.'<br />';
                  // some other things ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li> 
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

controller code:

```
public function traceDelete($traceID) {
    if ($traceId = $this->input->post('traceId')) {
    return $this->model_general->deleteTrace($traceId);
    }
    return false;
}
```

model code:

```
public function deleteTrace($id) {
    $this->db->where('trace_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('trace_tbl');
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 1 ? true:false;
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in firebug console for ajax? I think your ajax will throw 500 error.

Comment: @kishor yes.. i hit 500 error

Comment: Please post your error with the question

Comment: Ok, then you have to provide the proper url to your Ajax. E.g. http://localhost/index.php/your_controller/traceDelete

Comment: i think my javascript not working .. i didnt get correct value for myData .. not sure where the problem.. coz i dont see any error anymore.. manage to reach success:function(traceDelete) and get alert "Deleted"

Comment: @Julie check by placing a `console.log(myData)` underneath `var myData = DbNumberID`.Keep your console open to see the value in the var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the id attributes wrong. They are meant to be unique as in appear on **one** element and not multiple as you have done. (As well, id attributes cannot start with a digit.) There's really no need to put it on multiple containing elements as you can easily traverse to the parents or children with jQuery's [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), and [other traversing methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). However, this should not be the cause of your problem.

Now, what I do think is the cause of your problem is that you are passing the 2nd character of your id attribute into your AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // assign the ID e.g. "abc" to clickedID
        var clickedID = this.id; 
        // problem: assign the second character of your ID i.e. "b" into DbNumberID
        var DbNumberID = clickedID[1];
        // assign the same value to myData (which is redundant)
        var myData = DbNumberID; 

        $(this).hide(); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'traceDelete', 
            dataType:"text", 
            // sending "myData=b"
            data: { myData: myData }, 
            success:function(traceDelete){
                alert("Deleted");
                $(DbNumberID).fadeOut();
            },
            error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
});
```

I am not too familiar with CodeIgniter anymore, but you need to get value from the $_REQUEST or $_POST array or use their [built-in function](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data).

```
$myData = $this->input->post('myData'); // because you are sending myData
```

**EDIT**

This is untested but here's how I would do it.

***HTML***

First, let's use [HTML5 data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) call it `data-trace-id`. This will be used instead of your numerous improper usages of `id` attributes.

```
<ul id="responds">
<?php foreach ($line as $dataName => $contents) : ?>    
    <li data-trace-id="<?php echo $contents->trace_id ?>">
        <div class="grey-panel" style="text-align: right">
            <div class="del_wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="del_button" data-hover="tooltip" title="Delete this message <?php echo $contents->trace_id ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <?php echo $contents->trace_hdr ?><br />
                <?php echo $contents->trace_src ?><br />
                <?php echo $contents->trace_dest ?><br />
                <!-- etc -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </li> 
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

***JavaScript***

Next, let's simplify your JavaScript. I'll use the dreaded `alert()` for debugging purposes -- but it's usually better to use `console.log()`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#responds").on("click", ".del_button", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // keyword 'this' refers to the button that you clicked;
        // $(this) make a jQuery object out of the button;
        // always good idea to cache elements that you will re-using;
        var $li = $(this).closest('li');

        // get the associated trace ID from the list-item element;
        var traceId = $li.data('trace-id');

        alert('trace ID ' + traceId);

        // assuming you only want to hide the message only if it has been been successfully deleted from the DB?
        // if that is the case, then you have to wait for the AJAX response to tell you whether it was
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post', 
            url: 'traceDelete', 
            dataType: 'text',
            // notice how I am using 'traceId'? on the server-side, the data will accessible by using $_POST['traceId'] or $this->input->post('traceId') 
            data: { 'traceId': traceId },
            // look at the response sent to you;
            // if I am not mistaken (boolean) true and false get sent back as (strings) 1 or 0, respectively;
            // so if the response is 1, then it was successfully deleted
            success: function (res) {
                alert('AJAX response ' + res);
                if (res === '1') {
                    alert('hiding button');
                    // hide the message
                    $li.fadeOut();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

***PHP***

Lastly, we take the value from the $_POST array. Check whether there is a value: if so, delete the item; otherwise ignore it.

```
public function traceDelete() 
{
    if ($traceId = $this->input->post('traceId')) {
        echo $this->model_general->deleteTrace($traceId) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    echo '0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.. as I understand a lot from it.. However, it is still not working.. The trace ID is blank and AJAX response (res value) also blank

Comment: I already debug and confirm that there is value in data-trace-id.. but somehow didnt pass the value

Comment: To me, your past comments indicates that you have a PHP error. [Turn on your errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371046/1022914). Are you also posting to the correct URL? Should there not be more to the URL than just `traceDelete` such as the base URL prepended to it? The fact that you are getting a blank response means that you are not going to the request handler OR you have an error somewhere in your PHP.

Comment: I don't see any error.. all data populate accordingly.. earlier i hit 500 error after click on the delete button.. but solve it..(its a typo error)   Now i get blank value for data-trace-id..  I believe it goes to the function, otherwise, I wont see the trace-id for that data.. am I wrong?.. really stuck here.. i want to use ajax so i dont have to refresh the page each time user delete the trace.. hmmm

Comment: My apology. Change commas in the `alert()` to pluses (as shown in my edit). You should be able to see the values.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem... I notice.. my base URL is .../searchTrace
searchTrace is a function in Controller.. 
The flow of the system are as follows:
1. User search for a particular trace based on few search criteria..
2. System display list of traces (which may include unnecessary trace)
3. User can delete the unwanted traces by click on delete button
4. Final trace is saved / download.

But i don't think it is the cause

Comment: I get trace ID undefined

Comment: K, that's weird. Here is a quick [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNEeLy). Your first problem is that you are no longer getting the trace ID on the client-side. Are you sure you followed the same structure? In terms of your second problem, now that I think about it, inside the function `traceDelete()`, change your `return`s to `echo`s as you send an AJAX response by echo'ing/printing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128228/discussion-between-mikey-and-julie).

Answer (score 0):

remove `var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; var myData = DbNumberID;`, as its not needed. Directly assign `data: { myData: clickedID },`. Also get value of `myData` in controller via `POST`.

```
public function traceDelete() {

    $traceID = $this->input->post('myData');

    if($traceID)
        return $this->model_general->deleteTrace($traceID);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I did change it.. still not captured the traceID.. the value is blank..

Comment: alert `clickedID` after this statement `var clickedID = this.id; ` and check whether you get any value.

Comment: use `var clickedID = $(this).attr('id');` and check too whether value comes or not.

Comment: instead of `$("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {` use ` $("#responds .del_button").click(function(e){ ` . Add `var clickedID = $(this).attr('id');` and then try to alert and see.

Comment: Done that.. It similar to Mikey's suggestion but still fail to delete the trace